# R lapply, access elements of a list

Tags: r, lapply

I think I am missing something simple, but I am having trouble accessing elements of a list, in a `lapply`.

Problem: I have a number of files on a FTP I want to download and read. So I need to specify the location, download them and read them. All which I thought can be handled best with a few lists, but I can't really get it to work in my function.

I would like to be able to start with calling a `lapply(lst,...)` because I need both the variable name `(a)` and the url in the same function, to download & name them easily.

Code-example:

```
a <- "ftp://user:pass@url_A1" 
b <- "ftp://user:pass@url_B1" 
c <- "ftp://user:pass@url_C1" 
d <- "ftp://user:pass@url_D1"

lst <- list(a, b, c, d)
names(lst) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

Desired goal:

```
print(lst[[1]]), ...., print(lst[[4]])
```

What I've tried:

```
lapply(lst, 
function(x) print(x[[]]) 
)

# Error!
```

My real code looks something more like:

```
lapply(lst, 
       function(x) download.file(url = x[[]], # Error!  
                               destfile = paste0(lok, paste0(names(x), ".csv")),
                               quiet = FALSE)
      )
```

EDIT:

I know the `x[[]]` throws an error, it is just to illustrate what I would like to get.

Comment: First, remove the "`[[]]`", which `lapply()` does not need. Does it work then?

Comment: If I remove them, it prints `$a` and then the `url`, I need the element of the list `[[1]]` specifically. So, just the `url`, or else I can't use it.

Comment: You could probably use `rapply` or `sapply`, i.e. `rapply(lst, print)`, but it adds some additional line at the end

Comment: I suppose you wish to print out the current url in process:  `lapply(lst, function(x) { cat('Processing url:',x,'\n'); download.file(url = x, destfile = paste0(lok, paste0(names(x), ".csv")),quiet = FALSE) } )`

Comment: eh, why don't you `lapply(lst,print)` ?

Comment: @Ossan: it worked :)

@Matt: Because lapply(lst, print) gives me `lst[1]` and not `lst[[1]]`. I need the last because I need to use it as an url. Not saying this is the optimal solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
lapply(names(lst),function(x){
download.file(url = lst[[x]],
destfile = paste0(lok,paste0(x,".csv")),
quiet = FALSE)
}
```

This should work given `lok` is defined.